# Is there a way to dump all states/provinces/territories?

Tags: django

I'm currently writing a country/territory input form. You know, something like this:

[image]

I haven't really found another good way to do this, so here's what I'm doing. I'm using [`django-countries`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-countries), and simply doing a for loop in my template to dump all of the countries out to the HTML:

```
def myview(request):
    from django_countries import countries
    return direct_to_template(request, "template.html", { "countries": countries.COUNTRIES })

{% for country in countries %}
    <option value="{{country.0}}">{{country.1}}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Now comes the tricky part. I'd like to essentially take as much advantage of native controls as possible, so I'm looking to do something like this:

```
{% for country in territory_countries %}
    <optgroup label="{{country.0}}">
        {% for territory in country.1 %}
            <option value="{{territory.0}}">{{territory.1}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </optgroup> 
{% endfor %}
```

Clear as mud, right?

The first `COUNTRIES` list looks like this:

```
COUNTRIES = (
    ('US',  'United States'),
)
```

I'd like something that looks like this:

```
TERRITORIES = (
    ('US',
        ('AL', 'Alabama'),
        ('AK', 'Alaska'),
    ),
)
```

It doesn't have to look exactly like that, but it'd be nice if I could fit it into my design.

Am I going about this wrong? Is there a better, smarter way of doing this? Is there a Django module which is much smarter about this and uses actual models in the database?

It'd be much nicer to do:

```
countries = Country.objects.all()

<select id="countries">
    {% for country in countries %}
        <option value="{{country.abbr}}">{{country.name}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>

<select id="territories">
    {% for country in countries %}
        {% if country.territories %}
            <optgroup label="{{country.abbr}}">
                {% for territory in country.territories %}
                    <option value="{{territory.abbr}}">{{territory.name}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </optgroup>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Is there something to help me out with this? Should I just say "to heck with it" and build a Django module to do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, I definitely built a Django library to deal with this issue: [django-locality](http://github.com/rfkrocktk/django-locality)

Reap the benefits of my suffering.